# Set -1 to 0 while adding in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a database using DECIMAL type values for various tests on crude oil.  When running these tests you run into certain cases:
1.) Test was run and value is found;
2.) You can definitively say nothing is there (0 in database);
3.) Test was not run (NULL in database);
4.) There is something found, but testing is not accurate enough to discern exactly how much (-1 is used in the database for this case).

My problem here is that I need to return result sets as a sum of all 4.  I have been using a "SELECT property1+property1+... FROM..." type of query to do this.  I use 'WHERE ___ IS NOT NULL' to deal with case 3, but the problem is in case 4, I don't want to add -1, I want to add it as 0.  Is there any way I can do this with MySQL?  I'd really rather not get each result set separately and have to use PHP to deal with this, but I suppose I can if there is no way around it.

Also, before someone recommends it, there isn't too much I can do in the way of changing the database structure.  However, if you have some completely ingenious fix that requires that, I wouldn't be opposed to hearing it regardless.

EDIT: Thanks for all the quick replies everybody.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: What does your table look like? Do you use SUM or do you add several columns?

Comment: I don't use SUM - I just add any number of columns using '+'

Comment: Then using IF in your query is probably the best solution. As for an alternative : if you had one row per test, then you could use SUM on all non-NULL and positive values to get the same result.

Comment: Yup, IF seems to be working beautifully. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [if statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html):

```
property1 + property2 + property3 + IF(property4 > 0, property4, 0)
```

Comment: I like this - quite easy to implement it syntactically.

Answer (score 0):

if you do something like `... + cond4 + ...` you can replace it with .`.. + CASE WHEN cond4 == -1 THEN 0 ELSE cond4 END + ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  SUM(GREATEST(COALESCE(property1, 0), 0))
FROM    mytable
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `GREATEST` instead of `LEAST`?  Otherwise the `-1` will stay `-1`, and a `100` will become `0` (The exact opposite of the desired behavior)...

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the [Control Flow Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

```
SELECT property1 + property2 + property3 + IF(property4 > 0, property4, 0) WHERE _ IS NOT NULL
```